# I have a dataset and when I try to find the correlation of this dataset like df.corr() it the output is (_) in jupyter, NaN in spyder

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, correlation

My dataset looks like this, and my code is:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Admission_data.csv")
correlations = df.corr()
correlations


admit   gre gpa rank
0.0 380.0   3.609999895095825   3.0
1.0 660.0   3.6700000762939453  3.0
1.0 800.0   4.0 1.0
1.0 640.0   3.190000057220459   4.0
0.0 520.0   2.930000066757202   4.0
1.0 760.0   3.0 2.0
1.0 560.0   2.9800000190734863  1.0
0.0 400.0   3.0799999237060547  2.0
1.0 540.0   3.390000104904175   3.0
0.0 700.0   3.9200000762939453  2.0
0.0 800.0   4.0 4.0
0.0 440.0   3.2200000286102295  1.0
1.0 760.0   4.0 1.0
0.0 700.0   3.0799999237060547  2.0
1.0 700.0   4.0 1.0
0.0 480.0   3.440000057220459   3.0
0.0 780.0   3.869999885559082   4.0
0.0 360.0   2.559999942779541   3.0
0.0 800.0   3.75    2.0
1.0 540.0   3.809999942779541   1.0
0.0 500.0   3.1700000762939453  3.0
1.0 660.0   3.630000114440918   2.0
0.0 600.0   2.819999933242798   4.0
0.0 680.0   3.190000057220459   4.0
1.0 760.0   3.3499999046325684  2.0
1.0 800.0   3.6600000858306885  1.0
1.0 620.0   3.609999895095825   1.0
1.0 520.0   3.740000009536743   4.0
1.0 780.0   3.2200000286102295  2.0
0.0 520.0   3.2899999618530273  1.0
0.0 540.0   3.7799999713897705  4.0
0.0 760.0   3.3499999046325684  3.0
0.0 600.0   3.4000000953674316  3.0
1.0 800.0   4.0 3.0
0.0 360.0   3.140000104904175   1.0
0.0 400.0   3.049999952316284   2.0
0.0 580.0   3.25    1.0
0.0 520.0   2.9000000953674316  3.0
1.0 500.0   3.130000114440918   2.0
1.0 520.0   2.680000066757202   3.0
0.0 560.0   2.4200000762939453  2.0
1.0 580.0   3.319999933242798   2.0
1.0 600.0   3.1500000953674316  2.0
0.0 500.0   3.309999942779541   3.0
0.0 700.0   2.940000057220459   2.0
1.0 460.0   3.450000047683716   3.0
1.0 580.0   3.4600000381469727  2.0
0.0 500.0   2.9700000286102295  4.0
0.0 440.0   2.4800000190734863  4.0
0.0 400.0   3.3499999046325684  3.0
0.0 640.0   3.859999895095825   3.0
0.0 440.0   3.130000114440918   4.0
0.0 740.0   3.369999885559082   4.0
1.0 680.0   3.2699999809265137  2.0
0.0 660.0   3.3399999141693115  3.0
1.0 740.0   4.0 3.0
0.0 560.0   3.190000057220459   3.0
0.0 380.0   2.940000057220459   3.0
0.0 400.0   3.6500000953674316  2.0
0.0 600.0   2.819999933242798   4.0
1.0 620.0   3.180000066757202   2.0
0.0 560.0   3.319999933242798   4.0
0.0 640.0   3.6700000762939453  3.0
1.0 680.0   3.8499999046325684  3.0
0.0 580.0   4.0 3.0
0.0 600.0   3.5899999141693115  2.0
0.0 740.0   3.619999885559082   4.0
0.0 620.0   3.299999952316284   1.0
0.0 580.0   3.690000057220459   1.0
0.0 800.0   3.7300000190734863  1.0
0.0 640.0   4.0 3.0
0.0 300.0   2.9200000762939453  4.0
0.0 480.0   3.390000104904175   4.0
0.0 580.0   4.0 2.0
0.0 720.0   3.450000047683716   4.0
0.0 720.0   4.0 3.0
0.0 560.0   3.359999895095825   3.0
1.0 800.0   4.0 3.0
0.0 540.0   3.119999885559082   1.0
1.0 620.0   4.0 1.0
0.0 700.0   2.9000000953674316  4.0
0.0 620.0   3.069999933242798   2.0
0.0 500.0   2.7100000381469727  2.0
0.0 380.0   2.9100000858306885  4.0
1.0 500.0   3.5999999046325684  3.0
0.0 520.0   2.9800000190734863  2.0
0.0 600.0   3.319999933242798   2.0
0.0 600.0   3.4800000190734863  2.0
0.0 700.0   3.2799999713897705  1.0
1.0 660.0   4.0 2.0
0.0 700.0   3.8299999237060547  2.0
1.0 720.0   3.640000104904175   1.0
0.0 800.0   3.9000000953674316  2.0
0.0 580.0   2.930000066757202   2.0
1.0 660.0   3.440000057220459   2.0
0.0 660.0   3.3299999237060547  2.0
0.0 640.0   3.5199999809265137  4.0
0.0 480.0   3.569999933242798   2.0
0.0 700.0   2.880000114440918   2.0
0.0 400.0   3.309999942779541   3.0
```

I tried correlations methods, `method='pearson'` or `numeric_value=True` etc.. but nothing works

Comment: can you provide a picture of your dataset and highlight the columns which you are trying to find correlation between? Also can you post the code and error you might be getting?

Comment: I think the issue is with your dataset, kindly share the DataSet screenshot including headers and some sample rows.